# "Each" Closure and For Loop in Jenkins Parallel script issue

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline that basically reads a JSON file and prints out some values from it.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic


pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def environment = new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText('''
                        {                              
                          "list": [
                            {
                              "name": "service1"
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "service2"
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "NotAService"
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "AnotherDummyService-mock",
                            }  
                          ]
                        }
                        '''
                        )

                    def forLoopBuilders = [:]
                    for (artifact in environment.list) {
                        if (!artifact.name.contains("-mock")) {
                            println("Before parallel, the value is ${artifact.name}")
                            forLoopBuilders[artifact.name] = { println(artifact.name) }
                        }
                    }
                    parallel forLoopBuilders

                    def closureBuilders = [:]
                    environment.list.each { artifact ->
                        if (!artifact.name.contains("-mock")) {
                            println("Before parallel, the value is ${artifact.name}")
                            closureBuilders[artifact.name] = { println(artifact.name) }
                        }
                    }
                    parallel closureBuilders
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@NonCPS
def jsonParse(def json) {
    new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(json)
}
```

The *builders* variable is how I store stages that will run in parallel. Basically it is
`[stageA: What to do in this stageA, anotherStage: What to do in this anotherStage]`

The output is as below

```
10:20:53  Before parallel, the value is service1
10:20:53  [Pipeline] echo
10:20:53  Before parallel, the value is service2
10:20:53  [Pipeline] echo
10:20:53  Before parallel, the value is NotAService
10:20:53  [Pipeline] parallel
10:20:53  [Pipeline] { (Branch: service1)
10:20:53  [Pipeline] { (Branch: service2)
10:20:53  [Pipeline] { (Branch: NotAService)
10:20:53  [Pipeline] echo
10:20:53  AnotherDummyService-mock
10:20:53  [Pipeline] }
10:20:53  [Pipeline] echo
10:20:53  AnotherDummyService-mock
10:20:53  [Pipeline] }
10:20:53  [Pipeline] echo
10:20:53  AnotherDummyService-mock

10:20:53  [Pipeline] // parallel
10:20:53  [Pipeline] echo
10:20:53  Before parallel, the value is service1
10:20:53  [Pipeline] echo
10:20:54  Before parallel, the value is service2
10:20:54  [Pipeline] echo
10:20:54  Before parallel, the value is NotAService
10:20:55  [Pipeline] parallel
10:20:55  [Pipeline] { (Branch: service1)
10:20:55  [Pipeline] { (Branch: service2)
10:20:55  [Pipeline] { (Branch: NotAService)
10:20:55  [Pipeline] echo
10:20:55  service1
10:20:55  [Pipeline] }
10:20:55  [Pipeline] echo
10:20:55  service2
10:20:55  [Pipeline] }
10:20:55  [Pipeline] echo
10:20:55  NotAService
```

As you can see the outputs from running the parallel stages are different. Why is that so?

What I want is the output from parallel `forLoopBuilders` should be the same as that from `closureBuilders`.

Comment: When you can see a problem has nothing to do with Jenkins, but it's a Groovy problem you're facing, it's always good to reproduce the problem with a simple Groovy script so people can more easily assist you. In this question, you didn't have to post the whole Jenkins script at all, see the minimal snippet I used to reproduce the problem in my answer... that's all you could've posted (and others would've already helped you much earlier if you'd done that).

Comment: @Renato Hi, thanks for the advice. I actually was not sure if the my question was about Groovy or about Jenkins (I’m fairly new to both of them to be honest). And I also thought that someone might want to try running the script, then they could simply copy and paste what I post. Anyway I totally get your point and will try to follow

Comment: No problem... notice that this is good advice specially when you're learning new things: make sure you understand what's the source of the problem by experimenting with each hypothesis you come up with (i.e. is this a Groovy issue, or a Jenkins issue) individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the result of how closures within for loops capture the loop variable, `artifact` in your case.

There's only a single loop variable that keeps being re-assigned... so the closures capture that single variable, but once the loop ends, that variable will have the last value assigned to it, hence all closures will only see that value later.

You can see how that behaves by running this simple example in pure Groovy:

```
    def map = [
            'Service1': 's1',
            'Service2': 's2'
    ]
    def closures = []
    for (entry in map.entrySet()) {
        closures << { println "ENTRY: $entry" }
    }
    closures*.call()
```

This will print:

```
ENTRY: Service2=s2
ENTRY: Service2=s2
```

I.e. the closures capture the last value of the `entry` variable.

Groovy closures are smarter in capturing values, they actually create new variables on each run, so if you replace the for-loop with a `each { ... }` construct, it works:

```
    def map = [
            'Service1': 's1',
            'Service2': 's2'
    ]
    def closures = []
    map.entrySet().each { entry ->
        closures << { println "ENTRY: $entry" }
    }
    closures*.call()
```

Prints:

```
ENTRY: Service1=s1
ENTRY: Service2=s2
```

In your case, just just use `each { }` and it should do what you want.

**EDIT**

If you insist in using the for loop, you should do like you would do in Java and assign the current value to a new variable.

The following code has the same result as the one using `each`:

```
    def map = [
            'Service1': 's1',
            'Service2': 's2'
    ]
    def closures = []
    for (entry in map.entrySet()) {
        def value = entry
        closures << { println "ENTRY: $value" }
    }
    closures*.call()
```